# How do I modify the if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I was trying to do a very compact rps(rock, paper, scissors) and to make it work I used a very inefective but funcitonal logic that if the result of the variables was a certain value then it will win the p if not (this includes the draw) it will lose. More explanation at the bottom of the code, but I wanted to be if the value p and m passed through the diccionary table euqualed to 1 or 2 then it will execute the next line of code, but with the brakets it worked half, without it missed another types of operations and with the brakets in the expresion on the right of the == it missed another part. I noticed that it works if you put it like another expression like:

```
if table[p]-table[m] == 1 or table[p] - table[m] == -2
```

but since I wanted to be compact, i was wondering if there was any way to put it in the same expression, thanks.
PS: the variables have been wirtten with its full names to make it more understandable, this will not be the case in the final version.

```
    table = {'r':0, 'p':1, 's':2}
    p = input()
    m = input()
    if table[p]-table[m] == (1 or -2):
        print('w')
    
    else:
        print('l')
    
    '''
    s,p= 1w
    s,r=2l
    p,r =1w
    p,s =-1l
    r,s=-2w
    r,p=-1l
    
    w=1,1,-2
    l=-1,-1,2'''
```

Comment: ```if  table[p]-table[m] in (1, -2)```? You can use ```in``` keyword

Comment: `if (table[p]-table[m]) % 3 == 1`

Comment: @Sujay it says that the type 'int' is not iterable. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah, I saw that way of making the code, and it's very effective, but I was trying to use my own method. If there is no possible solution to my mothod then I will use this, thank you very much. :)

Comment: `print('lwl'[table[p]-table[m]])`

Comment: Though probably you'd really want `'dwl'` in order to also cover draws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `(1 or -2)` becomes just `1`, your

```
if table[p]-table[m] == (1 or -2):
```

is the same as:

```
if table[p]-table[m] == 1:
```

You can instead check membership in a collection of the possible values, for example:

```
if table[p]-table[m] in {1, -2}:
```

Or, since you just use it to print `w` or `l`, you can use Python's support for negative indexes and don't use `if` at all:

```
print('lwl'[table[p]-table[m]])
```

The complete program with further trickery:

```
t='rp'.find
print('lwl'[t(input())-t(input())])
```

Comment: Sorry if it is much to ask, but how did you declare that t was a dictionary without any curly-braces? and what does the find method do in this program? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a dictionary, just a function doing the same job, turning characters into their numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the 'modulo' operator?

```
if (table[p] - table[m]) % 3 == 1 :
    ....
```

Comment: Because see the comments under the question.

Comment: Btw this is Python, not C++, so you don't need the `+ 3`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, use print formatting option:

```
print(f"{'w' if table[p]-table[m] == 1 or table[p]-table[m] == 0 else '1'}")
```

---

The if statement with `1 or 2` was indeed wrong as pointed out by [@Perter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood) in the comments, because it would first compare `1 or 2` that will always evaluate to 1 and then compare the result with `table[p]-table[m]`.

Comment: Wow, thats very compact, but I was having the issue with the if statement and not with the compactiness of the code. Anyways, thanks  for theh help.

Comment: Oh i thougth you wanted a more compact version :(

Comment: No need to worry, I will use your formatting, but that wasn't my main concern. So in the end it's useful, thanks.

Comment: Non sense? I see no problems in this code, is perfectly python compatible with the inline if else statement...

Comment: `1 or -2` evaluates to `1`

Comment: @Armaggheddon I'm not surprised that you don't.

Comment: You could use `in {1,-2}`, not `== (1 or - 2)`

Comment: Yes I already edited the code to be correct. Thank you anyway for pointing out!